# Trouble with installating URI::Escape

Tags: perl, perl-module, conda

I have several perl installations that came along with various conda environments. Because of this one of the tools I am using is unable to access a PERL module `URI::Escape`:

Perl script to test module installations:

```
$ cat test.pl 
use Set::IntervalTree;
use DB_File;
use URI::Escape;
```

Current perl being used works okay:

```
$ which perl
/home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/envs/rnaseq-env/bin/perl
$ perl test.pl # runs okay
```

Trouble with URI::Escape using the perl installation used by my tool:

```
$ /home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/bin/perl test.pl 
Can't locate URI/Escape.pm in @INC (you may need to install the URI::Escape module) (@INC contains: /home/rathik/perl5/lib/perl5/5.22.0/x86_64-linux /home/rathik/perl5/lib/perl5/5.22.0 /home/rathik/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux /home/rathik/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/x86_64-linux /home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0 /home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/lib/perl5/5.22.0/x86_64-linux /home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/lib/perl5/5.22.0 .) at test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 3.
```

When I try to install it, it throws this error:

```
# install URI::Escape
/home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/bin/perl -MCPAN -e shell

OR

/home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/bin/cpan URI::Escape

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/old-base.t            (Wstat: 7680 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  4
  Non-zero exit status: 30
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=43, Tests=619,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.23 usr  0.07 sys +  1.60 cusr  0.47 csys =  2.37 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/43 test programs. 1/619 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz
Failed during this command:
 ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz                        : make_test NO
```

I am able to install `URI::Escape` using the current perl but not with the perl that's being used by my tool. How do I resolve the conflicts?

CPAN Installation Log:

```
Reading '/home/rathik/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 05 Mar 2017 21:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'URI::Escape'
Checksum for /home/rathik/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/rathik/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring E/ET/ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for URI
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz
  /home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for E/ET/ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz
cp lib/URI/sips.pm blib/lib/URI/sips.pm
cp lib/URI/sip.pm blib/lib/URI/sip.pm
cp lib/URI/snews.pm blib/lib/URI/snews.pm
cp lib/URI/WithBase.pm blib/lib/URI/WithBase.pm
cp lib/URI/file/Mac.pm blib/lib/URI/file/Mac.pm
cp lib/URI/ssh.pm blib/lib/URI/ssh.pm
cp lib/URI/file/OS2.pm blib/lib/URI/file/OS2.pm
cp lib/URI/Heuristic.pm blib/lib/URI/Heuristic.pm
cp lib/URI/file/QNX.pm blib/lib/URI/file/QNX.pm
cp lib/URI/_userpass.pm blib/lib/URI/_userpass.pm
cp lib/URI/_foreign.pm blib/lib/URI/_foreign.pm
cp lib/URI/tn3270.pm blib/lib/URI/tn3270.pm
cp lib/URI/file.pm blib/lib/URI/file.pm
cp lib/URI/rsync.pm blib/lib/URI/rsync.pm
cp lib/URI/ftp.pm blib/lib/URI/ftp.pm
cp lib/URI/Split.pm blib/lib/URI/Split.pm
cp lib/URI/file/Win32.pm blib/lib/URI/file/Win32.pm
cp lib/URI/URL.pm blib/lib/URI/URL.pm
cp lib/URI/pop.pm blib/lib/URI/pop.pm
cp lib/URI/_idna.pm blib/lib/URI/_idna.pm
cp lib/URI/file/Unix.pm blib/lib/URI/file/Unix.pm
cp lib/URI/rtspu.pm blib/lib/URI/rtspu.pm
cp lib/URI/QueryParam.pm blib/lib/URI/QueryParam.pm
cp lib/URI/sftp.pm blib/lib/URI/sftp.pm
cp lib/URI/ldapi.pm blib/lib/URI/ldapi.pm
cp lib/URI/file/Base.pm blib/lib/URI/file/Base.pm
cp lib/URI/_punycode.pm blib/lib/URI/_punycode.pm
cp lib/URI/_query.pm blib/lib/URI/_query.pm
cp lib/URI/data.pm blib/lib/URI/data.pm
cp lib/URI/urn.pm blib/lib/URI/urn.pm
cp lib/URI/_ldap.pm blib/lib/URI/_ldap.pm
cp lib/URI/rtsp.pm blib/lib/URI/rtsp.pm
cp lib/URI/IRI.pm blib/lib/URI/IRI.pm
cp lib/URI/_login.pm blib/lib/URI/_login.pm
cp lib/URI/telnet.pm blib/lib/URI/telnet.pm
cp lib/URI.pm blib/lib/URI.pm
cp lib/URI/nntp.pm blib/lib/URI/nntp.pm
cp lib/URI/urn/oid.pm blib/lib/URI/urn/oid.pm
cp lib/URI/urn/isbn.pm blib/lib/URI/urn/isbn.pm
cp lib/URI/gopher.pm blib/lib/URI/gopher.pm
cp lib/URI/ldaps.pm blib/lib/URI/ldaps.pm
cp lib/URI/_segment.pm blib/lib/URI/_segment.pm
cp lib/URI/news.pm blib/lib/URI/news.pm
cp lib/URI/rlogin.pm blib/lib/URI/rlogin.pm
cp lib/URI/mms.pm blib/lib/URI/mms.pm
cp lib/URI/http.pm blib/lib/URI/http.pm
cp lib/URI/mailto.pm blib/lib/URI/mailto.pm
cp lib/URI/Escape.pm blib/lib/URI/Escape.pm
cp lib/URI/ldap.pm blib/lib/URI/ldap.pm
cp lib/URI/https.pm blib/lib/URI/https.pm
cp lib/URI/_server.pm blib/lib/URI/_server.pm
cp lib/URI/_generic.pm blib/lib/URI/_generic.pm
cp lib/URI/file/FAT.pm blib/lib/URI/file/FAT.pm
Manifying 11 pod documents
  ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/abs.t ................... ok     
t/clone.t ................. ok   
t/cwd.t ................... ok   
t/data.t .................. ok     
t/distmanifest.t .......... skipped: these tests are for authors only!
t/escape-char.t ........... ok   
t/escape.t ................ ok     
t/file.t .................. ok     
t/ftp.t ................... ok     
t/generic.t ............... ok     
t/gopher.t ................ ok     
t/heuristic.t ............. ok     
t/http.t .................. ok     
t/idna.t .................. ok   
t/iri.t ................... ok     
t/ldap.t .................. ok     
t/mailto.t ................ ok   
t/mix.t ................... ok   
t/mms.t ................... ok   
t/news.t .................. ok   
t/num_eq.t ................ ok   
t/old-absconf.t ........... ok   
t/old-base.t .............. 1/? Error in tempdir() using /mnt/lustre/users/rathik/scratch/XXXXXXXXXX: Could not create directory /mnt/lustre/users/rathik/scratch/P_z_9i_Dit: Read-only file system at t/old-base.t line 615.
    # Child (newlocal test) exited without calling finalize()

#   Failed test 'newlocal test'
#   at /home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/lib/perl5/5.22.0/Test/Builder.pm line 279.
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
# Looks like your test exited with 30 just after 4.
t/old-base.t .............. Dubious, test returned 30 (wstat 7680, 0x1e00)
Failed 1/4 subtests 
t/old-file.t .............. ok     
t/old-relbase.t ........... ok   
t/path-segments.t ......... ok   
t/pop.t ................... ok   
t/punycode.t .............. ok     
t/query-param.t ........... ok     
t/query.t ................. ok     
t/rel.t ................... ok   
t/rfc2732.t ............... ok     
t/roy-test.t .............. ok       
t/rsync.t ................. ok   
t/rtsp.t .................. ok   
t/scheme-exceptions.t ..... ok   
t/sip.t ................... ok     
t/sort-hash-query-form.t .. ok   
t/split.t ................. ok     
t/storable.t .............. ok   
t/urn-isbn.t .............. skipped: Needs the Business::ISBN module installed
t/urn-oid.t ............... ok   
t/utf8.t .................. ok   

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/old-base.t            (Wstat: 7680 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  4
  Non-zero exit status: 30
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=43, Tests=619,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.21 usr  0.08 sys +  1.61 cusr  0.64 csys =  2.54 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/43 test programs. 1/619 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz
Failed during this command:
 ETHER/URI-1.71.tar.gz                        : make_test NO
```

Comment: Did you install URI::Escape as well?

Comment: @simbabque I misread my error but I have made edits to the question

Comment: The fourth test in `old-base.t` looks wrong to me. I would just force the installation as long as no other tests failed.

Comment: @Borodin Can you move this to an answer. This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @KomalRathi: I've thought again, and I'm wrong about the error. Forcing the installation will have ignored the result of the test, and it's important to know *why* that test failed. Please post the rest of your cpan log so that we can diagnose it.

Comment: @Borodin I have added the cpan log at the end of the question.

Comment: @KomalRathi: Thank you. It says that `/mnt/lustre/users/rathik/scratch` is read-only, which is odd. Do you know why that would be? Anyway, it's not a problem with the module so you can go ahead.

Comment: @Borodin thanks for pointing that out - I had set my TMPDIR to that path but looks like it was locked down a couple weeks back. This has been very helpful. I cannot close this question without accepting your answer so can you move your comment to an answer?

Comment: @KomalRathi: I'll write it up when I get back to a proper keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Each installation of the `perl` binary should have a corresponding installation of `cpan`. To install a module that will be visible to `/home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/bin/perl`, install it with `/home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/bin/cpan`.

Comment: This may not answer the question, but I will leave it here as a general tip.

Comment: I did try using that `/home/rathik/tools/miniconda3/bin/cpan URI::Escape` but it is still showing the same error.